# Python with Text File

Tags: python, text, gps, automation, arcgis

Trying to automate a process. I have a growing list of text files that never seems to go away. From that file, there is a request number, list of GPS coordinates and an email.

Optimal goal:

- Automatically create a map with the plotted points with a polygon around it with the title being the request number and have it emailed to the address in the txt file/

I would like try a few different options:

1. Automatically plot all the GPS points and create a polygon connecting them
2. Create a table that has all of the GPS points with the appropriate request number with it

I realize this is a large request but any parts of it being automated would be a huge help.

Thank you

Comment: So which part are you stuck on? It would also be helpful if you post any code you have so far as well.

Comment: To be honest this is starting from scratch. I am not exactly sure where to begin. It has been a while since I have written code. Making a process to automate the request# and GPS coordinates would be a huge help

Comment: So what is the question? I do not see a single question mark in your question, let alone any code that you tried so far.

Comment: I havent tried any code.

Comment: Is it possible to write a script that takes a text file and automatically makes a table of points with the job request number associated to each GPS coordinate

Comment: If the end result was like this that would be a huge help. Lat Long Request Email Address
40.6164 -80.01735 request 1 email 1
40.7434 -80.17465 request 1 email 1
40.8704 -80.33195 request 1 email 1
40.9974 -80.48925 request 1 email 1
41.1244 -80.64655 request 1 email 1
41.2514 -80.80385 request 1 email 1
41.3784 -80.96115 request 1 email 1
41.5054 -81.11845 request 2 email 2
41.6324 -81.27575 request 2 email 2
41.7594 -81.43305 request 2 email 2
41.8864 -81.59035 request 2 email 2
42.0134 -81.74765 request 2 email 2
42.1404 -81.90495 request 2 email 2